# Writing in background (Linux wget) to database JSON response from web-service

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wget

I have a big problem. I wrote script in jQuery which gets data from webservice by posing JSON and webservice by response sends me back data also in JSON.
The code looks like that:

```
function Product(date_from,date_to,API_KEY) {
var self = this;
self.productURI = 'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/DailySales?FromDate='+date_from+' 00:01  :00&ToDate='+date_to+' 00:01:00';
self.products = new Array();
self.productsDiv = "#products";

self.getAllProducts = function () {
   var req = self.pobierz_dane_ajax(self.productURI, "GET");
    req.done(function (data) {
        self.products = data;
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'write_transactions.php',
            data: { 
                save_transaction: dataString,
                date_from: date_from
            }
        });
    });
}

self.pobierz_dane_ajax = function (uri, method, data) {
    var request = {
        url: uri,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + API_KEY);
        }
    };
    return $.ajax(request);
}
```

}

I call my function like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var product = new Product('<?php echo $date_from; ?>','<?php echo $date_to; ?>','<?PHP echo $DE_API; ?>');
product.getAllProducts();
```

And in PHP script I parse JSON with PHP and write it to database.

Everything works fine when I call whole process by webpage (Chrome, Firefox). Problem starts when I call it in crontab in Linux by:

wget -O - 'https............'
But it just don't work.
I need to start this script in background so I need better solution....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you currently

- call a webpage via browser
- the webpage fetch data from an external api with JS (ajax)
- you parse the response and send it per POST to an additional PHP script (saves the data to database)

now you call the webpage from cron with wget but it does not work

The reason is, wget just fetch the page and display the HTML response, but does not run the JS-script!

Instead of wget you could use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). It basically acts as a headless browser and can for example be called from cron

Another possible solutions could be to rewrite some of your code and do everything in the php script directly

- PHP Script fetch data from API
- Same Script save data to database
- cronjob regulary call the php script with wget

Edit - suggesting solution for php api call

```
<?php
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => array(
                'Authorization: Basic ' . $API_KEY,
                'Content-type: application/json'
            )
         )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($API_URL, false, $context);

    //work with response / save to db
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I thought about rewriting it entirely in PHP but I don't know how pass GET with header via PHP, so this part:
 var request = {
        url: uri,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + API_KEY);
        }
    };
    return $.ajax(request);

Comment: look into my edit in my answer - with file_get_contents (or curl as a alternative) it should be easy to fetch the api data

Answer (score 0):

Helll Yeah! It was so easy :D

I am posting my solution for others :D

```
$remote_url = 'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

print($file);
```